# Is it possible to use values from the next row in custom AggregateWindowFunction

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

I'm using Spark 2.4 and implementing subclass of `AggregateWindowFunction`. I need to look at the next row. Unfortunately I can't use `Lead` expression when implementing `updateExpressions` because `Lead` inherits from `Unevaluable` trait and using it results in runtime exception.

Is it possible to inspect values from the next row in custom `AggregateWindowFunction` or do I have to add one extra step before calling custom `AggregateWindowFunction` (this step can use `lead` to get values from the next row so I can use those values in custom function)?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to solve that cannot be achieved my existing `org.apache.sparl.sql.functions`? If you can, please provide sample input and expected output. Thanks.